# Angular keeps generating browser application bundle

Tags: angular, abp

At my work, I've transitioned from a laptop to a stationary for more power, but in the setup, I've encountered a problem. I can't get my Angular frontend to compile anymore.
I have the same version of node.js as on the laptop (14.7.0), and same npm and yarn versions.

When I then run the ´ng serve --open´ command, it compiles the code and it says it compiles sucessfully, but it immidiately starts to generate application bundles again, as if there is some change to the code it wants to implement. This happens again several times, until node.js runs out of allocated memory.

The frontend is a part of the ABP architecture. I have run ´npm install´and ´yarn´.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "stella",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    "debug": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "build:test": "ng build --configuration test",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@abp/ng.components": "^4.4.4",
    "@abp/ng.core": "^4.4.4",
    "@abp/ng.setting-management": "^4.4.4",
    "@abp/ng.theme.shared": "^4.4.4",
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.10",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.10",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.10",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.10",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.10",
    "@material/dialog": "^8.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.3.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.3",
    "@volo/abp.commercial.ng.ui": "^4.4.4",
    "@volo/abp.ng.account": "^4.4.4",
    "@volo/abp.ng.audit-logging": "^4.4.4",
    "@volo/abp.ng.identity": "^4.4.4",
    "@volo/abp.ng.identity-server": "^4.4.4",
    "@volo/abp.ng.language-management": "^4.4.4",
    "@volo/abp.ng.saas": "^4.4.4",
    "@volo/abp.ng.text-template-management": "^4.4.4",
    "@volo/abp.ng.theme.lepton": "^4.4.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.17",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.3",
    "ng2-date-picker": "11.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^3.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@abp/ng.schematics": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.6",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.1000.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.10",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.12",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^10.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that an installation of the dropbox app was causing a loop effect, where it constantly synced my files, and so the project would constantly reload, never quite finishing.

The kicker here is that the Git-repository was located in my documents folder, and dropbox had chosen to sync those, even though it was not shown as part of my synced paths, and the dropbox being a company driven dropbox, with it's seperate folder structure.